# histogram of a dicom image in matlab

Tags: matlab, histogram, dicom

I'm trying to plot a histogram in matlab of a dicom image. This is a medical image format, and the colormap is not the standard [0 255] gray levels. so the imhist is not working for me. any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have some code? What type of error do you get? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly, DICOM images use `uint16` for their pixels' values.

Have you tried

```
imhist( I, max(I(:)) );
```

To force `imhist` to use the full range of `uint16` values?

Alternatively, you can always use [`hist`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hist.html) instead of [`imhist`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imhist.html).

```
hist( I(:), max(I(:)) );
```

Answer (score 2):

If the image consists of floating point data (single or double), `imhist` expects the data to be in the range [0 1]. Try normalizing the the input to `imhist`, like this:

```
imhist(data/max(data(:)))
```

For other data types, [read the `imhist` documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imhist.html) (especially the tips section) to learn how it works.